# Powershell multiple dynamic buttons

Tags: powershell

I built a dynamic Powershell GUI but i have trouble getting my buttons to work correctly.

I created a function to add texboxes and buttons. However they do not correspond correctly at this point. because i'm not sure how to bind the `add_click` to a specific textbox.

Here is the example code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300)  

$ButtonAdd = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonAdd.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,20)
$ButtonAdd.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,30)
$ButtonAdd.Text = 'Add'
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonAdd)

$global:Counter = 0
$global:ButtonPosY = 20
$global:DefaultTextValue = ""

$ButtonAdd.Add_Click{Add-Fields}

Function Create-Button {
    param ( $ButtonPosY, $TextBoxPosY)

    $TextBoxField = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $TextBoxField.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(181,$TextBoxPosY)
    $TextBoxField.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,30)
    $TextBoxField.Text = $global:DefaultTextValue
    New-Variable -name TextBoxField$global:Counter -Value $TextBoxField -Scope Global -Force
    $Form.controls.Add($((Get-Variable -name TextBoxField$global:Counter).value))

    $ButtonClick = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $ButtonClick.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,$global:ButtonPosY)
    $ButtonClick.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,30)
    $ButtonClick.Text = 'Click'
    New-Variable -name ButtonClick$global:Counter -Value $ButtonClick -Scope Global -Force
    $Form.controls.Add($((Get-Variable -name ButtonClick$global:Counter).value))

    $ButtonClick.Add_Click({
        $((Get-Variable -name TextBoxField$global:Counter -Scope Global).value).Text = 'hello'
    })
}

Function Add-Fields {

    $global:Counter = $global:Counter + 1
    $global:ButtonPosY = $global:ButtonPosY + 40

    Create-Button -TextBoxPosY $global:ButtonPosY -ButtonPosY $global:ButtonPosY

}

Create-Button -TextBoxPosY 21 -ButtonPosY 20

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

If the `click` button is pressed each time after new input is added everything works fine. however if multiple input fields are added first and then the `click` button is pressed the code breaks.

The Problem is here:

```
    $ButtonClick.Add_Click({...})
```

I don't know how to add the counter (in my case `$global:Counter`) to the `$ButtonClick` variable as in `$ButtonClick0, $ButtonClick1, ... etc`. So right now when i add more buttons by calling the function the input will always be applied to the last added textbox since the `add_click` is not linked to a individual `$ButtonClick0` variable.

How would this be done right?

Comment: you cannot add event handlers in function. Handlers requires specific control objects. You can return the Object created in function and use the returned object to call `$ReturnObject.Add_Click({'whatever'})`

Comment: How would i then know what button was pushed and then store the returned value in the correct TextBox? Please provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some serious reading i figured it out.

A name needs to be added to `$ButtonClick`

```
$ButtonClick.Name = $global:Counter
```

And the `Add_Click` event should look the following:

```
$ButtonClick.Add_Click({
    [System.Object]$Sender = $args[0]
    $((Get-Variable -name ('TextBoxField' + [int]$Sender.Name)).value).Text = 'hello'
})
```

However i don't know if this is how it should be done. Please post your solution if it looks different.